# for some reason my concatenation in this if statement is not working. (probably an easy answer for most of you)

Tags: c#

I'm sure i am missing something simple whenever i run this part of the console app it will print the "You entered " and ignore everything else i try to concatenate.

```
if (Console.ReadLine() == "quit")
        {
            string output = "Goodbye.";
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
        else
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string output = "You entered " + input + ".";
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

Comment: You've already called `ReadLine` in your `if` statement, and the next time you're calling it, its looking for another line.  Store the return of `ReadLine` in a variable and use it in your if and your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "quit")
{
    string output = "Goodbye.";
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
else
{
    string output = "You entered " + input + ".";
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to get 2 times input data. Try that:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "quit")
        {
            string output = "Goodbye.";
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
        else
        {
            string output = "You entered " + input + ".";
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as @MarcL.Allen's

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine for me. Check this: https://repl.it/C5qj

Also pay attention that each time you call the `Console.ReadLine()` it will wait for the user input. So your code will wait for the user input **two** times (for each of the `Console.ReadLine()` there). First time it will check that it isn’t equal to `”quit”`, second time it will print the result to the console.